# Methodology to stop remote autostart celery servers on start up when need changes

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a rather big project with a fairly simple structure.A VPC(virtual private cloud) have a banch of servers.The main server contains RabbitMQ and MySQL server binded to a private ip and a script i wrote for the autoscaling of consumer's servers,and a number of other servers running celery workers(consumers) with supervisor(autostart,autorestart) that are closed and open on demand.The problem I'm facing now is that in production i cannot edit the source code of the droplets as they will auto bind to the broker if i open the worker server ,and they may consume a task from the queue(which can be very long and costly on execution).Schema:
[image]

The only solution i came up with is pre-ban the ip from the consumer i want to edit on firewall(ufw),which is very messy as it will log a banch of errors and can be tedious for a big number of remote servers.Is there a better solution to achieve this?

Comment: I have a feeling you can accomplish what you need using the [Worker signals](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-signals)

Comment: Wasnt aware of this but still somehow i need a variable outside the server its self since the server is closed,and i need to manipulate what i want before it starts.Thx for your comment pretty helpful for future usecases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prety fast to ask a question.The best solution was to add a kill function on start up of celery worker that connects to the backend database and query a mode argument.So now i can edit the backend database,and choose if i want the worker to connect or exit on start up.